# Does a view have to be "full screen" when using Storyboard?

Tags: ios

I've been using one Storyboard file, and several customized NIBs for custom controls in the app. I'm reading on storyboard and trying to improve the app. But I think I'm confused now

1. Is it possible, to have a scene when using the storyboard, that is NOT full-screen?
2. If yes, who should be handling the case, say, the user touches "outside" of this view that is smaller than the full screen?
3. How, if I have some "view objects" that is only shown when I get some data from the server? When this customized control is shown, touching it leads to other views. Can I also use the storyboard and segues for this?

Thanks!